# Integral of product of Bessel functions of different order

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I know that if the orders of the Bessel functions were the same, the following integral will give a representation for the dirac delta distribution

$$ k\int_0^\infty r J_0(kr)J_0(k'r)\,dr =\delta(k-k')$$

Is there a known, notable result for the analogous integral with Bessel functions of different orders, for example

$$ I_{02}(k,k')=k\int_0^\infty r J_2(kr)J_0(k'r)\,dr =?$$

Comment: For general `v` is:$$k \int_0^{\infty } r J_v(k r) J_0(\text{kprime} r) \, dr=\frac{2 k G_{2,2}^{1,1}\left(\frac{k^2}{\text{kprime}^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0 \\
 \frac{v}{2},-\frac{v}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{\text{kprime}^2}$$ where: `G`  is **MeijerG** function.